# Why does my variable turn into 0 when what I declared as that variable does not equal 0?

Tags: javascript, html, variables, alert, scrolltop

Okay so my goal was to first calculate the distance between the top of the page and the part of the page the viewer is at, so basically the part of the top of the page the viewer cannot see, the distance in pixels of this area (only vertical).

So that when they entered another page the:

"function codeAddress() {$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: "**scrollTop**" });}"

,would scroll them down with the amount of pixels that they had scrolled down on a previous html page, and this distance would be stored in the "scrollTop" variable.

But since it wasnt working I wanted to test what value the "scrollTop" variable would give and the alert(scrollTop) gave me the value '0'. but when I use alert(...) , and at the ... I give **exactly** what was behind the '=' "scrollTop = ..." I get the right value. So it turns out that the value from the variable turns to 0 whilst the value of everything behind the '=' sign does not equal 0.

I can't figure what I'm not seeing, anybody any clues?

Here's a JSFiddle with my entire page, there is a button halfway and in my page it gives the '0' value for the second alert and in the Fiddle it gives 'undefined' still weird..

https://jsfiddle.net/56sb4gty/

```
<script type="text/javascript">                                         

    function codeAddress() {$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: "scrollTop" });}
    window.onload = codeAddress;

    var scrollTop = $('body, html').scrollTop()

      function myFunction() { 
                              alert($('body, html').scrollTop())
                              alert(scrollTop)      };

</script>
    <script src="scrollTop.js"></script>
```

Comment: `"scrollTop"` is probably not a valid value to animate to ?

Comment: That's possible but then why does the alert(scrolltop) and alert($('body, html').scrollTop()) give a different value this confused me alot. Since:
var scrollTop **=** $('body, html').scrollTop() ..

Answer (score 0):

As adeneo says you're trying to scroll to a string called "scrollTop" which doesn't make any sense, it should be `scrollTop: SOME_NUMBER`.

I assume you save the last position on a debounced scroll event, or navigation click and save it to session/localStorage.

Then on a new page you scroll to that position. Something like..

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  try {
    // On load see if there is a scroll pos and go there.
    var lastYPos = +localStorage.getItem('scrollYPos');
    if (lastYPos) {
      console.log('Setting scroll pos to:', lastYPos);
      window.scrollTo(0, lastYPos);
    }

    // On navigation click or debounced resize event..
    someResizeOrClickEvent(() => localStorage.setItem('scrollYPos', window.scrollY));
  } catch (error) {
    // This will happen in Safari private browsing when accessing localStorage
    console.error(error);
  }
});
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick answer and taking a look at my problem at all but I'm not that good with Javascript, isnt it easier to take my example where I used 'scrollTop' as a variable and turn this into an integer instead of a string? And also I dont understand why the two alerts seem to give me different values since they should match, right?
Because the alert that does not use the variable does give me the right Y position offset so I could use it to scroll down the next page if I store it but for some reason when I turn it into a variable it turns into zero?

Comment: Actually no, `$('body, html').scrollTop()` is a jquery function which you are calling and getting the result of which is a number, but not the number that you want (to get the current Y scroll position use `window.scrollY`, this should have been saved on your previous page). `scrollTop` is the same as `window.scrollTop` which doesn't exist

Comment: Hey there Dominic, I get your point but I've changed it and the second value (where I use a variable) still turns to '0'. Check out this Fiddle pls:
https://jsfiddle.net/0wj7hw50/3/
And also when I replace the "window.pageYOffset" with "window.yScroll or window.Yscroll" as you called, I get undefined from both alerts instead of a value and a '0'.

Comment: It's `window.scrollY` not `yScroll` or `Yscroll` ;) but anyway window.pageYOffset should work too - they are *exactly* the same thing (pageYOffset is just an alias for it) https://jsfiddle.net/0wj7hw50/4/ Note that I attached those functions to window but it's better to unobtrusively add events to elements by doing addEventListener on them

Comment: Thanks for the reply, first of all, I found out that your fiddle doesnt work in IE, which isnt a problem, I'll just use chrome. But if I use your code and put it in my script and alert the value of ''savedScrollY'' I still get '0'.

https://jsfiddle.net/5dyugw4o/

Comment: Ah I finnaly found out what the problem was. Apparently I had to declare my ScrollTop variable in the function I was using it in, instead of directly above it. Still thanks tho.